# margin-top/bottom % not works in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, margin

I have 2 divs arrange column in flex, I want their distance = 1%, this is my code:

```
<div class="container1" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
   <div class="div1" style="height: 100px; margin-bottom: 1%; background-color: green;"> This is div 1 </div>
   <div class="div2" style="height: 100px; background-color: blue"> This is div 2 </div>
</div>
```

It works well in IE or Chrome but not works in Firefox.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

It's due to `display:flex` is not working well with `%` in Firefox. So here you need to used `display:block` to `container1` div.

> **Use this code when you are using `%` in margin-bottom.**

```
<div class="container1" style="display: block; flex-direction: column;">
   <div class="div1" style="height: 100px; margin-bottom: 1%; background-color: green;"> This is div 1 </div>
   <div class="div2" style="height: 100px; background-color: blue"> This is div 2 </div>
</div>
```

> **Please try this code when you are using PX not % in margin-bottom.**

```
<div class="container1" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
   <div class="div1" style="height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: green;"> This is div 1 </div>
   <div class="div2" style="height: 100px; background-color: blue"> This is div 2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why have -1 in your answer, but it work like a charm, you saved my day. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `px` instead of `%` to define margin, Its working everywhere (all browsers)

```html
<div class="container1" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
   <div class="div1" style="height: 100px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color: green;"> This is div 1 </div>
   <div class="div2" style="height: 100px; background-color: blue"> This is div 2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I can use px but I really want use % instead of px

Comment: `display: flex;` is not working with %